# How to build a new list from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a python list that contains a set of objects (a class that has it's own
properties and functions and variables). I would like to extract some of the list elements and create a new list.

My question is: Are the new list elments going to remain same or they will be considered new instances of the class when I extract them from list?

For example: `List layer = [myclass1, myclass2, myclass3]`

I want new list `layernew = [myclass1]` or any such combination. How can  I extract the items. When I print directly layer and new layer (by using `newlayer=layer[0:1]`) I see that it gives me the same instance reference of the object.

Comment: if the question is, are the item in my new list the same, yes they are. You are only copying the reference to your object as such, your lists contain only references

Comment: Lists don't contain objects, they contain *references* to objects.  By the way, try not to use the phrase "set of objects" unless you mean a `set` - it is confusing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the new list elments going to remain same or they will be considered new instances of the class when I extract them from list.

They'll be the same. Demo:

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

a = [Widget(4), Widget(8), Widget(15)]
b = a[0:1]

print a[0] is b[0]
```

The output is `True`, so `a[0]` and `b[0]` are references to the same object.

One way to change this behavior is to use the `copy` module's `deepcopy` method. This will attempt to duplicate the object you give it and return a referentially distinct object with identical values.

```
import copy

class Widget:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

a = [Widget(4), Widget(8), Widget(15)]
b = copy.deepcopy(a[0:1])

print a[0] is b[0]
#result: False
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reference for the deepcopy. Would like to accept the answer but can't at the moment.

Comment: Hi, my object instances were getting messed up. Deepcopy really did solve the problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user3840530: well, I suppose you can accept this answer now?

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same objects. You can do identity tests with `is` in python.

```
layernew[0] is layer[0]  # True
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.